# Trouble Importing csv into pgAdmin 4 - Internal Server Error: 'columns'

Tags: sql, database, import, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I have added six empty tables with SQL into pgAdmin. I have six csv files with the same columns and I am trying to add them in concordance with an entity relationship diagram that includes column names, and key information. 5 have imported relatively easily. Trying to work out a different error with the last. However, I am frequently getting this error:

[internal server error: 'columns'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HSqs.png)

This error seems to occurs before the request to add the csv can even be created. when I look at the "columns" tab in the import/export utility, none of the columns in the csv I am trying to import appear. When I use

```
SELECT * FROM table;
```

I can tell that the table columns have been created with the right names. This error is confusingly inconsistent as sometimes when I drop and add a table, using the same code I did previously, it seems to appear and disappear without cause. I have tried editing the SQL that I use to create the tables, changing the order in which I import the tables, changing FK and PK around in different tables, and reinstalling different versions of PGAdmin.

Comment: add error reproting and post the complete error message, when you know where it happens add the code as text into your question

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved it by refreshing the DB connection (right click DB > refresh)

I think it doesn't know that you have added the columns so it's trying to tell you to add them, so refreshing should fix the confusion.